# Intermittent failure of xConnect contact creation

Tags: xconnect

We are currently experiencing an issue in our Production environment (CD or CM in a scaled CD, CM, PRC, REP and xConnect setup) where client returns contact about 10% of the time when using the example xConnect contact creation code [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/set-contact-facets-217864.html#idm45860102363808).

```
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model;
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Entities;
using Sitecore.XConnect;
using Sitecore.XConnect.Client;
using Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model;

namespace Documentation
{
    public class TrackAnonymousContacts
    {
        public void Example()
        {
            if (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew)
            {
                var manager = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager;

                if (manager != null)
                {
                    Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactSaveMode = ContactSaveMode.AlwaysSave;
                    manager.SaveContactToCollectionDb(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact);

                    var trackerIdentifier = new IdentifiedContactReference(Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Constants.IdentifierSource, Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId.ToString("N"));

                    using (XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var contact = client.Get<Contact>(trackerIdentifier, new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions());

                            if (contact != null)
                            {
                                client.SetFacet<PersonalInformation>(contact, PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, new PersonalInformation()
                                {
                                    FirstName = "Myrtle" // Replace with real input source
                                });

                                client.Submit();

                                manager.RemoveFromSession(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId);
                                Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Contact = manager.LoadContact(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
                        {
                            // Manage conflicts / exceptions
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We do not see this issue in any other environments and it is impacting our conversion / identification of users. We've deployed additional logging and various potential solutions eg. Retry contact creation X times, using different manager methods or first identifying the user before pushing contact facets.

It is also worth noting it's running on 9.0 Update-2 and that there are no errors in the logs for the contact creation in either Sitecore or xConnect.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Comment: What is the error message you receive?

Comment: There are no error messages -  that is part of the problem. I only know contact is null as I was able to add extra logging.

Comment: What is your server topology? How many CD servers you have? Are they load balanced? How you share session data between them?

Comment: Development and Production environments are configured in the example same topology / settings. Environment is running as CD,CM, PRC, REP and XConnect (AIO). Session is configured at a 20 minute expiry as InProc as we only have 1 x CD server.

Comment: Add logging to see what `Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId` is when you are running `SaveContactToCollectionDb` then see if you can find the contact with that ID in the database (check `xdb_collection.ContactIdentifiers` table and see if you can find the ContactId in the `Identifiers` column. You may have to translate the ContactId from Guid.ToString("N") to hex values first (as that is what is stored in the `Identifiers` column). If the contact cannot be found after having run `SaveContactToCollectionDb` you still won't know what's wrong, but you should have narrowed the problem down a bit :)

Comment: What Sitecore version?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is expecting the contact to be in the xConnect server when you request it. And maybe because of the xConnect load/network it may not be there yet.

```
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactSaveMode = ContactSaveMode.AlwaysSave;
manager.SaveContactToCollectionDb(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact);
var trackerIdentifier = new IdentifiedContactReference(Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Constants.IdentifierSource, Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId.ToString("N"));
```

Use this code and if the `Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew` force the contact to be pushed back to xConnect before you ask for it. This happens in the `SaveContact()` function.

```
// here is your tracker identifier
var trackerIdentifier = GetContactReference();


public IdentifiedContactReference GetContactReference()
{
    // get the contact id from the current contact
    var id = GetContactId();

    // if the contact is new or has no identifiers
    var anon = Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew || Tracker.Current.Contact.Identifiers.Count == 0;

    // if the user is anon, get the xD.Tracker identifier, else get the one we found
    return anon
        ? new IdentifiedContactReference(Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Constants.IdentifierSource, Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId.ToString("N"))
        : new IdentifiedContactReference(id.Source, id.Identifier);
}

public Analytics.Model.Entities.ContactIdentifier GetContactId()
{
    if (Tracker.Current?.Contact == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew)
    {
        // write the contact to xConnect so we can work with it
        this.SaveContact();
    }

    return Tracker.Current.Contact.Identifiers.FirstOrDefault();
}

public void SaveContact()
{
    // we need the contract to be saved to xConnect. It is only in session now
    Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactSaveMode = ContactSaveMode.AlwaysSave;
    this.contactManager.SaveContactToCollectionDb(Tracker.Current.Contact);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what difference there is in the code you provided as I am already checking if they are new and calling SaveContactToCollectionDb().

Comment: @Svenkle you are right. I did not notice that you were already doing SaveContactToCollectionDb. You code only runs if (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew). Could that be your issue? You don't have code to run if they are not flagged as new. Once you save them to xConnect, they are no longer new. I am always returning Tracker.Current.Contact.Identifiers.FirstOrDefault(); as the identifier. And only saving if IsNew.